# Hidden field value rendering incorrect date to view model

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

PeriodFrom = 05/10/2016

PeriodTo = 06/10/2016

Above properties date format is **dd/mm/yyyy** as you can see from the below screen shot.

[image]

However when i click on the submit button, the values are copied to a view model.

PeriodFrom becomes 10/05/2016 and PeriodTo becomes 10/05/2016

[image]

The 10 becomes the day and the 5 becomes the month. Not sure why this is happening. Could someone please advise ?

**Startup**

```
var supportCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-GB")
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
            SupportedCultures = supportCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportCultures
        });
```

**View**

```
<form asp-controller="BragManagement" asp-action="Export" method="get" role="form">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.PeriodFrom" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.PeriodTo" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.BragValueTitle" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink">Export</button>
 </form>
```

**Method**

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Export(UserVoteDetailSearchViewModel model)
    {

        var result = _userRepository.GetAllUserVoteDetails(model);

        _reportService.GenerateReport(result);

        return View();
    }
```

**View model**

```
public class UserVoteDetailSearchViewModel
{
    public DateTime? PeriodFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PeriodTo { get; set; }
    public string BragValueTitle { get; set; }

    public List<UserVoteDetail> UserVoteDetailList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It means the culture on your server is one that accepts dates in the `M/dd/yyyy` format (not `dd/MM/yyyy`). You can change your server culure or you can pass the dates in ISO format - `yyyy-MM-dd` which will bind correctly irrespective of the server culture

Comment: Will you please share your form submit code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke code has been submitted.

Comment: @LateshtClick code has been submitted.

Comment: Guys the format is correct. However when i populate the view model the 10 becomes the day and the 5 becomes the month. It should be the other way round. It's a very weird issue.